# How to lazy merge a few enumerables by some rule

Tags: c#, .net, linq, morelinq

For example I have to sequences:

```
IEnumerable<float> List1 = new float[] {
    0f, 0.1f, 0.5f, 0.9f, // < 1
    1f, 1.1f, 1.5f, 1.9f, // < 2
    2f, 2.9f // < 3
    };

IEnumerable<int> List2 = new int[] {
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4
    };
```

I need to get next result:

```
0f, 0.1f, 0.5f, 0.9f, 1,
1f, 1.1f, 1.5f, 1.9f, 2,
2f, 2.9f, 3,
4
```

I wrote two functions but thay are not lazy!

```
private static IEnumerable<object> Merge(IEnumerable<float> list1, IEnumerable<int> list2) {
    var queue1 = new Queue<float>( list1 ); // it is not lazy!!
    var queue2 = new Queue<int>( list2 );

    while (queue1.Any() && queue2.Any()) {
        if (queue1.Peek() < queue2.Peek()) {
            yield return queue1.Dequeue();
        } else {
            yield return queue2.Dequeue();
        }
    }

    while (queue1.Any()) {
        yield return queue1.Dequeue();
    }

    while (queue2.Any()) {
        yield return queue2.Dequeue();
    }
}


private static IEnumerable<object> Merge2(IEnumerable<float> list1, IEnumerable<int> list2) {
    var queue1 = new Queue<float>( list1 ); // it is not lazy!!

    foreach (var item2 in list2) {
        while (queue1.Any() && queue1.Peek() < item2) {
            yield return queue1.Dequeue();
        }
        yield return item2;
    }
}
```

How can I do it with lazy evaluation?

Comment: Are you saying that your data sequences aren't already ordered by timestamp?

Comment: could you share sample input/output ?

Comment: I think you should look into Observables in Rx c# as part of a processing pipeline. https://jack-vanlightly.com/blog/2018/4/19/processing-pipelines-series-reactive-extensions-rxnet

Comment: `OrderBy` is lazy. Why can't you use it?

Comment: @Enigmativity in .NET Framework, OrderBy is not lazy. I can't find any information on whether that's changed in .NET Core.

Comment: OrderBy is not lazy. You can not sort infinity sequence!

Comment: Brett Caswell, I learned RX and I came to the conclusion that this is hell. And I don't want to use push model when I need to pull.

Comment: I completely updated the question.

Comment: @canton7 - `OrderBy` is lazy. When I run the code `var ordered = list.OrderBy(x => x.Name);`, for example, the variable `ordered` is only evaluated when it is later enumerated - it's not evaluated at the time it is created. That's what lazy means.

Comment: @wishmaster35 - `OrderBy` is lazy. Just because you can't sort infinite sequences doesn't mean it's not lazy.

Comment: @Enigmativity No, look at the implementation on referencesource. It's quicksort. It sorts the entire collection when the first element is enumerated. There have been numerous articles on ways it could be improved using a partial sort: this would be a true lazy sort, where only the work required to pick the next item in the order is done when the next item is enumerated. Because it sorts the whole thing in one go, even if a single item is requested, it is not lazy.

Comment: @canton7 - The crux of the wording is "when the first element is enumerated". When you call `OrderBy` you are not enumerating any elements. That's why it is lazy. It's only when you use it in a `foreach` or a `.ToArray()` etc that it is evaluated. `OrderBy` is lazy.

Comment: This is a problem of terminology. Under [MSDN definitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/deferred-execution-and-lazy-evaluation-in-linq-to-xml), `OrderBy` is deferred but not lazy. "Deferred execution means that the evaluation of an expression is delayed until its realized value is actually required. […] In lazy evaluation, a single element of the source collection is processed during each call to the iterator." See also article by [Jon Skeet](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/03/25/just-how-lazy-are-you/)

Comment: @Enigmativity so long as you understand that OrderBy does not implement a true lazy sorting algorithm ([see here](http://faithlife.codes/blog/2010/04/a_truly_lazy_orderby_in_linq/)), and that it does a complete eager sort of the entire collection in one go, albeit deferred, then yes its just a problem of nomenclature. But please do appreciate the difference between an eager sort, which OrderBy does, and a lazy sort, as described in my link above, as the difference in algorithm and implications is important.

Comment: @canton7 - Point taken. Deferred, not lazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a comfortable wrapper for `IEnumerator<T>` and more beautiful `Merge` method.

```
public static IEnumerable<object> Merge(IEnumerable<float> list1, IEnumerable<int> list2) {
    using (var enumerator1 = new SmartEnumerator<float>( list1.GetEnumerator() ))
    using (var enumerator2 = new SmartEnumerator<int>( list2.GetEnumerator() )) {

        while (!enumerator1.IsCompleted && !enumerator2.IsCompleted) {
            if (enumerator1.Peek() < enumerator2.Peek()) {
                yield return enumerator1.Pull();
            } else {
                yield return enumerator2.Pull();
            }
        }

        while (!enumerator1.IsCompleted) {
            yield return enumerator1.Pull();
        }

        while (!enumerator2.IsCompleted) {
            yield return enumerator2.Pull();
        }
    }
}


public class SmartEnumerator<T> : IDisposable {

    private readonly IEnumerator<T> target;
    private bool hasValue;
    private T Value => target.Current;

    public bool IsCompleted {
        get {
            RequestNextValueIfNeeded();
            return !hasValue;
        }
    }


    public SmartEnumerator(IEnumerator<T> target) {
        this.target = target;
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        target.Dispose();
    }


    public T Peek() {
        if (IsCompleted && !hasValue) throw new InvalidOperationException( "Enumerator is already completed" );

        RequestNextValueIfNeeded();
        return Value;
    }

    public T Pull() {
        if (IsCompleted && !hasValue) throw new InvalidOperationException( "Enumerator is already completed" );

        RequestNextValueIfNeeded();
        hasValue = false;
        return Value;
    }


    // Helpers
    private void RequestNextValueIfNeeded() {
        if (!hasValue) RequestNextValue();
    }

    private void RequestNextValue() {
        hasValue = target.MoveNext();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have two sequences that are already respectively ordered, and you want to return the ordered sequence that results from merging the two. This sequence is generated lazily, reading just the next element from each sequence at a time.

```
private static IEnumerable<object> Merge(IEnumerable<float> sequence1, IEnumerable<int> sequence2)
{
    // Get enumerators for iterating through the two sequences.
    using (var enumerator1 = sequence1.GetEnumerator())
    using (var enumerator2 = sequence2.GetEnumerator())
    {
        var remaining1 = enumerator1.MoveNext();
        var remaining2 = enumerator2.MoveNext();

        while (remaining1 && remaining2)
        {
            if (enumerator1.Current < enumerator2.Current)
            {
                yield return enumerator1.Current;
                remaining1 = enumerator1.MoveNext();
            }
            else
            {
                yield return enumerator2.Current;
                remaining2 = enumerator2.MoveNext();
            }
        }

        if (remaining1)
        {
            do { yield return enumerator1.Current; }
            while (enumerator1.MoveNext());
        }
        else if (remaining2)
        {
            do { yield return enumerator2.Current; }
            while (enumerator2.MoveNext());
        }
    }
}
```

Update: Based on Enigmativity's comment, you can generalize this to work with any comparable type:

```
private static IEnumerable<T> Merge<T>(IEnumerable<T> sequence1, IEnumerable<T> sequence2, IComparer<T> comparer = null)
{
    if (comparer == null)
        comparer = Comparer<T>.Default;

    // Get enumerators for iterating through the two sequences.
    using (var enumerator1 = sequence1.GetEnumerator())
    using (var enumerator2 = sequence2.GetEnumerator())
    {
        var remaining1 = enumerator1.MoveNext();
        var remaining2 = enumerator2.MoveNext();

        while (remaining1 && remaining2)
        {
            if (comparer.Compare(enumerator1.Current, enumerator2.Current) < 0)
            {
                yield return enumerator1.Current;
                remaining1 = enumerator1.MoveNext();
            }
            else
            {
                yield return enumerator2.Current;
                remaining2 = enumerator2.MoveNext();
            }
        }

        if (remaining1)
        {
            do { yield return enumerator1.Current; }
            while (enumerator1.MoveNext());
        }
        else if (remaining2)
        {
            do { yield return enumerator2.Current; }
            while (enumerator2.MoveNext());
        }
    }
}
```

However, for the OP's example of merging `float[]` with `int[]`, one would need to cast the second list:

```
var result = Merge(List1, List2.Select(x => (float)x));
```

Comment: It's an excellent answer. I would have preferred to see the signature as `IEnumerable<T> Merge<T>(IEnumerable<T> sequence1, IEnumerable<T> sequence2) where T : IComparable` so that it's applicable to all `IComparable` types.